# Program does not finish with exit code 0 in Java despite printing out all output properly

Tags: java, runtime-error, exit-code

So, I am doing a competitive programming problem and when I submit my code, it says I am getting a run time error. I think this is because my code is not outputting the "exited with exit code 0" once the program has complied and runned. On IntelliJ, the correct output is printed but once again, it does not say that the code has exited with "exit code 0."

Here is the Code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = kb.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
            int N = kb.nextInt();
            int trace = 0;
            int[][] grid = new int[N][N];
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                    grid[j][k] = kb.nextInt();
                    if(j == k)
                        trace += grid[j][k];
                }
            }
            int rowsWithASameNumber = 0, columnsWithASameNumber = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                int[] row = new int[N];
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    row[k] = grid[j][k];
                Arrays.sort(row);
                for (int k = 0; k < N - 1; k++) {
                    if(row[k] == row[k + 1]) {
                        rowsWithASameNumber++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                int[] row = new int[N];
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    row[k] = grid[k][j];
                Arrays.sort(row);
                for (int k = 0; k < N - 1; k++) {
                    if(row[k] == row[k + 1]) {
                        columnsWithASameNumber++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Case #" + (i + 1) + ": " + trace + " " + rowsWithASameNumber + " " + columnsWithASameNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Was wondering if I was missing something very obvious or if the problem is not even about the exit code 0 thing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, it is because you are getting a runtime error, that is to say a `RuntimeException`, with whatever input they are providing. Nothing to do with the exit code, which is zero for this program, as you haven't called `System.exit()`. The 'exit code 0' thing is not printed by any normal Java program.

Comment: My guess is that you are not reading the input correctly (either reading past the end of input, or the token isn't an integer). You could put ` `try` block around to catch an unexpected exception - the test output will give you one bit of information. That or exit early.

Comment: @user207421 - But IntelliJ outputs this after running and exiting correctly

Comment: @Dinesh Polisetty please provide input and output sample plus the stack trace that you are getting  so we can try to help you. Oh and dont forget  always close the scanner!. ``kb.close();``

Comment: @Marius That's my point. It comes from the IDE. The program doesn't print it.

Comment: @user207421 - That's exactly what I referred to in my answer. If it doesn't print it, then it hasn't stopped executing. I don't see any reason for downvoting that answer?

Comment: @Marius It gets a runtime error. Please read the question.

Comment: @user207421 - We haven't seen any runtime error. He only says he submitted it to some contest and gets a reply that there's a runtime error. I don't know what that means, and neither do you. It would also be strange that IntelliJ doesn't report the error.

Comment: @Marius If you don't know what it means, you can't know that it means that the program didn't terminate. You can't have it both ways. 'Runtime error' normally means a `RuntimeException` of some kind. If it didn't terminate one would expect them to have said so. And the competition site certainly won't be running these programs under an IDE.

Answer (score -1):

> On IntelliJ, the correct output is printed but once again, it does not say that the >code has exited with "exit code 0."

Probably, this means your program doesn't exit.

Comment: @user207421 - Well, if his program doesn't exit correctly, I'd call that a runtime error

Comment: So what should I do if it doesn't exit?

Comment: So what should I do to exit the code if that is the problem?

Comment: There is a very large difference between 'doesn't exit' and 'doesn't exit correctly'. Obviously it doesn't exit correctly, but that's not what you wrote in your answer: and if it was what you meant to write, you would only be repeating information that is already in the question, not providing a solution.

Comment: And if the program really doesn't terminate you should offer a diagnosis as to why not, and a solution. I see no reason why this would loop forever. Your explanation?